# FreeNAS: Snapshots on replicated datasets disappear

Tags: snapshot, freenas, replication

I am running 2 FreeNAS boxes (let's call them *A* and *B*).

*A* is the production server which contains multiple datasets on mirrored/striped ZFS volumes for sharing via cifs, nfs, etc.
*A* is configured to create snapshots for its datasets, most of them are created hourly and live somewhere between 3 days and 2 months. A replication task is created for each dataset to store it on server *B*.

*B* is the backup server which has a bit more storage due to a striped/RAID-Z2 configuration. *B* is setup to create additional snapshots on the replicated datasets with a larger interval and a longer lifetime (e.g. 3 months for all datasets).

Unfortunately the new snapshots created by *B* disappear after a while - I guess it is a replication task which cleans up the replicated snapshots and (by accident?) deletes also *B's* snapshots.

My first idea was to handle snapshot cleanup on *B* by myself (e.g. via cron job) but I was not able to stop deletion of snapshots at all. Even though I disabled "Delete stale snapshots on remote system" in *A's* replication task, old snapshots are still removed.

The FreeNAS version is 9.10-STABLE-201604111739

I saw this bug https://bugs.freenas.org/issues/12692 which describes a similar problem - but according to the corresponding revisions the fix should already be available in my FreeNAS version.

So, which task/script/process deletes my snapshots?

Thanks,
Florian

---

Update:

I built a test setup using 2 virtualboxes to recreate the scenario above.

I found out that the "Delete stale snapshots on remote system" feature actually works - but as soon as I add an additional snapshot task on *B*, this task removes the stale snapshots itself. Not sure if this is intended behavior...

Now I have to find out why *B's* snapshots are deleted.

Comment: Still happens. At least now I know that replication/snapshotting should run in different time-slots - a *B* snapshot created at the wrong time led to a permanently failing *A* replication. Nevertheless *B* snapshots are still deleted without any trace.... Nothing verbose in /var/log/messages.

Comment: I guess snapshotting on the "pull" side is a no-go because it is seen as a dataset modification for ZFS's send which needs to be rollbacked first. Need to find a different solution - maybe disable snapshots on *B* and and run cron-controlled ZFS send into local files ...